# How do I use search sails.js models using REST without Shortcuts blueprint?

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I have turned off shortcuts blueprints (/model/findAll wont work) and now I want to search the model, using REST, but I did not find anything, is there any documentation or do I have to write my own views for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org), the CRUD and REST blueprint routes are enabled for development, but for production I suggest that you have your own actions that can find/create/update/delete models in the given controller

Sails automatically maps the actions in your controllers to corresponding routes, without you having to manually configure them, to turn this off: set the *actions* flag to false in the **config/controllers.js** file

This is best explained with an example, so here is a basic model that has some RESTful routes

**models/User.js**

Our model has two attributes and does not enforce uniqueness

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    email: 'string'
  }

};
```

**controllers/UserController.js**

Our controller has two actions, **findAll** returns all users and **findByName** returns users with given name

```
module.exports = {

  findAll: function (req, res) {
    User.find().done(function (err, users) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(400);
      } else {
        res.send(users);
      }
    });
  },

  findByName: function(req, res) {
    var name = req.param('name');
    User.findByName(name).done(function (err, users) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(400);
      } else {
        res.send(users);
      }
    });
  }

};
```

**config/routes.js**

Our routes configuration has two routes that respond only to GET requests, /user/all will run the **findAll** action and /user/name/:name will run **findByName** action with *name* given as a parameter in the URL

```
module.exports.routes = {

  'GET /user/all': 'UserController.findAll',
  'GET /user/name/:name': 'UserController.findByName'

};
```

For more information, be sure to check out the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers) of controllers in Sails.js

Comment: I dont really thing that it is necessary to turn off rest api - it can be controlled by policies, no?

Comment: Yes, if you decide to keep the Sails REST API enabled in production, you can set the policies that apply to your controllers and routes (along with the automatically generated routes) in the **config/policies.js** file.

Comment: @scott - Could you show us an example of how to integrate a policy with the default REST API?

Comment: For anyone coming across this - .done has been depreciated and should now be .exec (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1607).

Comment: I think this is out of date again, I believe this is now called "blueprint routes" and "blueprint actions" https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api

Answer (score 4):

Just an update to the previous post, since I couldn't find anyone else who mentioned this and I don't have enough reputation to comment, the `connections.js` file has been removed in more recent versions of Sails.js. These config options are now in the `blueprints.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Updating [scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19294727/205034) using Promise, ES6 and custom Response

```
    findAll: function (req, res) {
        User.find().then(users => {
            res.send(users);
        }).catch(() => {
            res.badRequest('Error in GET');
        });
    },

    findByName: function(req, res) {
        var name = req.param('name');
        User.findByName(name).then(users => {
            res.send(users);
        }).catch(() => {
            res.badRequest('Error in GET');
        });
    },
```